# Express JS, issue with routes, getting 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In app.js, I have the route,

```
app.use('/na1', lolapi);
```

In lolapi.js, I have

```
router.get('/:api', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.api);
    res.send('got /na1/api');
});
```

But if I hit,

http://localhost:3000/na1/lol/match/v3/matchlists/by-account/123456/,

I am getting the following message in terminal

```
GET /na1/lol/match/v3/matchlists/by-account/123456/ 404 10.208 ms
```

Shouldn't it get directed to '/na1' route? I am unable to figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to match `lol/match/v3/matchlists/by-account/123456/` as route param.

You need to create regex route:

```
router.get(/^\/(.+)/, function(req, res, next) {
    let api = req.params[0];
    console.log(`Got ${api}`);
    res.send('got /na1/api');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't it get directed to '/na1' route?

No, the path clearly doesn't match. Your route expects a single path and the URL you're accessing has multiple.

If you want a catch all then you would need

```
router.get('/*', ....);
```